# не проходит git push

Tags: git, github, git-push

Здравствуйте. У меня при добавлении файлов на git следующая ситуация. При git add все нормально как обычно, при git commit тоже, а когда пишу git push origin master появляется такая ошибка:

```
*To git@github.com:triodjangopiter/junior.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:triodjangopiter/junior.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.*
```

Помогите пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: А вы в свой репозиторий пытаетесь запушить?

Comment: похоже, у вас там есть изменения, которых ещё нет локально. Посмотрите, что показывает `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`

Comment: git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all он мне тут такое выкатил листов на 10

Comment: Да в свой репозиторий пушу.

Comment: Но что делать пока не понятно(((

Comment: Я тут нашел мне кажется решение git push --force но не уверен что-бы опять не наломать дров. Подскажите можно так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с командой:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

Всем спасибо.

Comment: А это вы в какой ветке делали?

Comment: А у меня всего одна. Других нет пока только начинаю.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что локальный и удалённый master расходились на сколько-то коммитов. Так что наверняка вы сначала сделали `git pull` и подтянули изменения.

Answer (score -1):

Сначала сделайте:
   git pull origin master
Потом:
   git push origin master

Comment: Не стоит просто так `git pull` делать, т.к. будет лишний мерж в свой мастер, а потом этот мерж запушится обратно.

Comment: А что еще что-то страшное случится?